# How to save my data in a 3d matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have 300 matrix of size 50x50 that each of them is the answer of my function. To doing this I made a zero matrix of size 50x50 called J and then put it in a loop that each time the answer of my function would save to J. For each round of the loop these J matrices must be put in one element of my 3d array, I try to do this but I'm not sure is it correct or not. In addition I don't know is there any better solution or not. Thanks.

My code is:

```
import numpy as np    
l=300
ts=50
#JointEntropy(X,Y,K) is my function
Jt=np.zeros(shape=(l,ts,ts))
J=np.zeros(shape=(ts,ts))
for i in range(1,l):
    #this loop is used put each parts of my original data in Ti and Dc is my data
    Ti=Dc[i-1][0:lw-1][0:ts-1]
    for j in range(1,ts):
        #this loop is used to each column of Ti as an array in X1 to be used in JointEntropy function 
        X1=Ti[j-1][0:lw-1]
        for z in range(1,ts):
        ##this loop is used to each column of Ti as an array in X2 to be used in JointEntropy function
            X2=Ti[z-1][0:lw-1]
            J[j-1][z-1]=JointEntropy(X1,X2,k)
    Jt[i-1][0:ts-1][0:ts-1]=J
```

Comment: You probably have an error (undesired behavior) : `range(1,l)` goes from 1 to l-1, so `Jt[l-1]` remains full of zeroes.

Comment: what is `lw`? What value does it have?

Comment: 'lw' is the length of axis that is 1e4.

Comment: Dear Massias you are right and I fix that but the problem is still remain.

Comment: Indexing of a 3d array should be written as `Jt[i-1, 0:ts-1, 0:ts-1]`.  It applies each slice to a different dimension.  Your version applies each to the first.  Are `Dc` and `Ti` arrays as well, or deeply nested lists?

Comment: Based on your description ( your code is unclear ), you have a function that return 300 of `(50,50)` arrays and you want to simply put the result in a one `(300,50,50)` array??

Comment: @farhawa yes thats exactly what I want to do